# document locking returns not expected value

Tags: java, xpages

I have a function in which I would like to check if a user can set a lock on document. If so I know the user can edit the document.

```
public boolean canWriteDocument(String docId, String userName) {
    boolean canWrite = false;
    Session session = null;
    session = getCurrentSession();
    try {
        Database db = session.getDatabase("", this.activeDb);

        if (db.isDocumentLockingEnabled()) {
            //Document locking is enabled

            Document doc = db.getDocumentByUNID(docId);
            if (doc.lock(userName)) {
                canWrite = true;
                System.out.println("document can be locked by user");
                doc.unlock();
            } else {
                System.out.println("document can NOT be locked by user");
            }
        } else {
            //Document locking is NOT enabled
        }

    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // fail silently
        System.out.println("failure docLock");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return canWrite;
}
```

I call the function as followed:
canWriteDocument("99DE330A432849AFC125803400313C73", "CN=John Doe/O=quintessens")

However there must be something wrong because when the user (with ACL Author access level) is not listed in the field of type Authors it returns true.

When I lower the ACL access level to Reader the returned value is still true.

Anyone can explain why this is happening?

Comment: Can he "Write Public Documents"?

Comment: if I enable/disable that Privilige the outcome is always true.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the database access level is cached within the server. Try rebooting the server (if it's a development environment) or testing with a brand new user that has never been in the ACL before.

If `Database.queryAccess()` is also not correct, that would confirm caching is the issue.

(It's possible that the two ways of checking access work differently under the hood, so if `queryAccess()` returns the correct value, it may not categorically mean the database locking option should.)

Comment: I can confirm the queryAccess methods returns the correct value.

Comment: if I remove doc.unlock() I can confirm that the $writers field is added to the document with the username. the user has a acl level of reader but manages to lock the document.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth could you be more specific?

Comment: _I would like to check if a user can set a lock on document. If so I know the user can edit the document._ Seems user can lock document even though he is not able to edit it. So check additionally for appropriate access in ACL - `Database.queryAccess()` and for Author access compare content of authors fields with `@UserNamesList()` (not needed for Editor and up)

Comment: Also look into Mastering XPages Second Edition book - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33269859/206265